# Show results from mysql query with php

Tags: mysql

I have following code:

```
$query = "SELECT ads.*,
       trafficsource.name AS trafficsource,
       trafficsource.id AS trafficsourse_id,
       FROM ads
           JOIN trafficsource ON ads.trafficsourceId = trafficsource.id
        WHERE advertiserId = '$advertiser_id'";

        $mysqli = new mysqli();
        $mysqli->connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'adsbase');
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<h2>Traffic Sources: {$row['trafficsource']}</h2>";
        }
```

This code show results like:

```
Traffic Sources: Example1
Traffic Sources: Example2
Traffic Sources: Example2
Traffic Sources: Example1
Traffic Sources: Example2
Traffic Sources: Example1
```

What I want and can't figure out is to show results like:

```
Traffic Sources: Example1, Example2
```

So without duplicates and also all in one line.

Comment: removing PHP tag - you got just problem writing correct query, so anything but SQL is irrelevant.

Comment: Why do you collect so much and use (in this example) so little? If you have to fetch all the data, you have to modify the PHP code; if not, it's better to change the query itself.

Comment: Read about GROUP_CONCAT

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nearly had it:

```
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $trafficeSources = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $trafficSources[] = $row['trafficsource'];
    }

    echo '<h2>Traffic Sources: ' . implode(', ', $trafficSources) . '</h2>';
```

### EDIT: Query using DISTINCT

I'm assuming you only need the traffic source name, but feel free to add more columns back in if they're required. Bear in mind though that the DISTINCT applies to a distinct combination of all rows returned, so it may be possible that you could end up with duplicate traffic sources if other selected columns differ.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT trafficsource.name AS trafficsource
          FROM ads
          JOIN trafficsource ON ads.trafficsourceId = trafficsource.id
          WHERE advertiserId = '$advertiser_id'";
```

Comment: I was just about to edit my answer to use implode, beat me to it.

Comment: Note that this answer means you are not dealing with duplicates... you need to check whether the current $row is already in the array or not.

Comment: Yeah good point. Although this would be better handled by using a `SELECT DISTINCT ...` query instead (and only selecting relevant columns), in which case this code will be fine.

Comment: Can you post query with SELECT DISTINCT. I'm trying to make it work with it but getting only errors.

Comment: If you're using `mysqli` you should be using SQL placeholders. Seeing things like `$advertiser_id` directly in a query is terrifying.

Answer (score 0):

Use Group by in 'trafficsource' in query and then in while loop concat each value of $row['trafficsource'] to other and echo it outside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this small solution:

```
     $trafic = array();
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                if(!in_array($trafic)) $trafic[] = $row['trafficsource']
    }
    if(!empty($trafic)){
      echo  '<h2>Traffic Sources:' . imlode(',', $trafic) .'</h2>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$trafficSources = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if(!in_array($row['trafficsource'], $trafficSources) {
        $trafficSources[] = $row['trafficsource'];
    }
}

echo "<h2>Traffic Sources: ".implode(', ', $trafficSources)."</h2>";
```